# Can't find min function after using opencv2

Tags: c++, opencv, namespaces

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

void increase_brigntness(Mat& im,int g)
{
    Mat lut(1,256,CV_8UC3);

    for(int i=0;i<256;++i)
        for(int c=0;c<3;++c)
            lut.at<Vec3b>(i)[c]=min(i+g,255);

    LUT(im,lut,im);
}
```

However, compiler can't find min(int,int) function in std because I've used namespace cv. How could I still use min function?

Comment: Can you post the *exact* error message? Because unless I'm mistaken, `i+j` will promote to `unsigned int`, not `int`, and thus will fail trying to find a `min(unsigned int, int)` where there is no such beast. [See it fail live](https://ideone.com/Hw6WO7)

Comment: @WhozCraig That looks like the answer. Although clobbering the namespaces doesn't help.

Comment: @juanchopanza likely so. you already have an answer up. feel free to rip off the failure sample from ideone and i'll uptick =P

Comment: @WhozCraig, thx~ I forgot to delete unsigned when I post this question.

Comment: @WhozCraig What a peculiar turn of events. Resurrected my answer.

Comment: @juanchopanza ... and up ticked =P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quick fix: call `std::min`:

```
lut.at<Vec3b>(i)[c] = std::min(i+g,255);
```

Long term fix: do not say `using namespace std;` or `using namespace cv;`. [It is a bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice). Namespaces were invented to avoid this kind of problem. You are just negating all the benefits of having them.